# On time laravel scheduler command I want to run in background if fail then run again on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu, server, digital-ocean

Currently i am using `nohup php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 &` but some 3 or 4 days later it kills. I want a permanent solution. I tried to create supervisor but it runs again and again but i am looking only one time run in background. If i `Autostart=false` its not ruining on background.  Some one can help i will be great full to you. I have not vast knowledge on Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

When using the scheduler, you only need to add the following Cron entry to your server. If you do not know how to add Cron entries to your server, consider using a service such as Laravel Forge which can manage the Cron entries for you:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. When the schedule:run command is executed, Laravel will evaluate your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling

Comment: Деня Василич thanks for you comment but problem is Every minute I don't need i need only once and it keep alive on background.

Comment: As I understand, the task scheduler doesn't start as a daemon.  At startup, it looks to see if there is a task that is not completed at the current moment, performs it, and turns off.  Therefore, we must put it in cron for every minute of it